# Different footprints for different surface mount Resistor packaging?

Tags: pcb, resistors, pcb-design, packages, footprint

When using the same surface mount package size (0402) for all my resistors on a board, but using resistors from different manufacturers or with different resistance values, should I create a different footprint for each manufacturer?

In other words, are all 0402 resistor footprints the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all footprints are necessarily the same when pulled from manufacturers' datasheets, and different manufacturers will have different recommendations for different situations. There may be minor variations from manufacturer to manufacturer. This is why I always make my own libraries, to keep styles consistent and to standardize on footprint sizes. I make three of each resistor/capacitor size, based on IPC recommendations: "L", "N", and "M", standing for "Least", "Nominal", and "Most". "Least" means the pads are at their smallest, making that package best for dense boards. On the other hand, where boards are very sparse or where I plan to solder by hand, I might select "M" meaning maximum pad sizes.

Make your own libraries and do not create separate footprints for each manufacturer. Standardize. It's well worth the effort.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, in your personal libraries, you would have 3 footprints (L,N and M) for your 0402 resistors, then you would always use those regardless of manufacturers or specs (as long as it's still 0402)?

Comment: @FrancisPoirier That is correct. Dimensions from different manufacturers will be close enough to fit on the footprints, so it is much better to have three standard versions

Comment: For a given SMD package size, are you using the same land pattern for resistors and capacitors?

Comment: @DanielK. No, I specify different footprints for caps and resistors. Fillet size will likely be different (resistors are generally much shorter than capacitors) so the calculations are likely to be different for the pad size